# Set take profit based on stop loss of previous lowest low/highest high

Tags: pine-script

I am writing a Tradingview strategy in PineScript based on a few different indicators, and I want to set a take profit targets based on the stop loss percentage, e.g.; if a stop loss based on previous lowest low is <2.5%, then I want to have TP 5x of this, but if the previous lowest low was >2.5% then I want TP of 4x.

Here is the current version of the TP/SL part of the code, which isn't working.

```
// ENTRY

strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, when=long)
strategy.entry("SHORT", strategy.short, when=short)

// LONG SL & TP

stopPerlong = (close-ta.lowest(low, 10)) / ta.lowest(low, 10)   

takePerlong = if stopPerlong > 0.05 
    stopPerlong * 3
    
else if stopPerlong > 0.025
    stopPerlong * 4

else if stopPerlong < 0.025
    stopPerlong * 5

else
    na
    
// SHORT SL & TP

stopPershort = (close-ta.highest(high, 10)) / ta.highest(high, 10)    

takePershort = if stopPershort < -0.05 
    stopPerlong * 3
    
else if stopPershort < -0.025
    stopPerlong * 4

else if stopPershort > -0.025
    stopPerlong * 5

else
    na
    

// DEPLOYING TP & SL

longStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stopPerlong)
shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stopPershort)
shortTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - takePershort)
longTake = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takePerlong)

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Long", stop=longStop, limit=longTake)
if strategy.position_size < 0 
    strategy.exit(id="Close Short", stop=shortStop, limit=shortTake)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example of how I would set my stop loss and take profit in Version 5. Let us assume I want to open a position on a bullish engulfing pattern and close it accordingly to what I have calculated as stop loss and take profit.

Declaration statement. I think only "close_entries_rule = "ANY" is something you should place since it seems it control the "from_entry" in strategy.exit().

```
strategy(title="Bullish Engulfing Pattern", overlay=true, close_entries_rule = "ANY", precision = 16, initial_capital = 10000 , default_qty_value = 1, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity)
```

*Detect if you have an opened a position.*

```
bool inTrade = strategy.position_size > 0
```

*If so count the bars so you know when the condition was true the last time.*

```
int countBars = ta.barssince(inTrade == false)
```

*Set your Take profit.*

```
int crv = 3
```

*Get your entry price.*

```
float entry = strategy.position_avg_price
```

*"Save" the values you need for your calculation of the stop loss. ta.barssince starts counting when your position is open. So you can refer back to candle you want.*

```
float candleLow = open[countBars]
float atr = ta.atr(14)[countBars]
```

*Calculate your Stop Loss and then your Take Profit. I prefer to use the ATR indicator to define my Stop Loss. In this case I use the open (candleLow) of the candle before opening the position.*

```
float sl = candleLow - atr
float tp = entry + (crv * (entry - sl[1]))
```

*Get the percentage value of both.*

```
float slInPercent = 1 - ((entry - sl) / entry)
float tpInPercent = 1 + (((entry - sl) / entry) * crv)
```

*Open your position*

```
if bullishEngulfing
    strategy.entry(id = "long", direction = strategy.long)
```

*Set your sl and tp values when a position is open using percentage values.*

```
if inTrade == true
    strategy.exit(id = "Exit Long", from_entry="long", stop = strategy.position_avg_price * slInPercent, limit = strategy.position_avg_price * tpInPercent, comment_loss = "Hit by stop loss", comment_profit = "Took profit!")
```

I hope this gives you kind of an idea.
Best wishes!

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Will continue to push on developing the indicator with this in mind, and post if I get the final script to work 